# Natural isomorphisms of the forgetful functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $U: \mathbf{Groups} \rightarrow \mathbf{Sets}$ be the forgetful functor. Must every natural transformation $\eta: U \rightarrow U$ be a natural isomorphism?

Comment: Nice question! Does it come from a textbook? if yes, which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $U$ is represented by $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, we have (by Yoneda) $\hom(U,U) \cong U(\mathbb{Z},+)=\mathbb{Z}$. If $z$ is an integer, the corresponding natural transformation $U \to U$ is given by $U(G) \to U(G),~g \mapsto g^z$ for groups $G$. From this it can be checked that actually we have an isomorphism of monoids $(\hom(U,U),\circ) \cong (\mathbb{Z},*)$. Since the only invertible elements of $(\mathbb{Z},*)$ are $\pm 1$, there are lots of natural transformations which are no isomorphisms, for example $g \mapsto g^2$.

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question, but I am a bit groggy right now, but what is g and what is g^z? are you describing the components of natural transformation $\eta (z)$ ?

Comment: @magma Martin describes the isomorphism $\mathbb Z \to \hom_{[\mathbf{Groups},\mathbf{Sets}]}(U,U)$ as the morphism mapping $z \in \mathbb Z$ to the natural transformation $\eta \colon U \to U$ defined at point $G \in \mathbf{Groups}$ as $\eta_G \colon g \mapsto g^z$.

Comment: Thank you @Pece I have seen the corresponding edit